# How to extract json response in windows phone?

Tags: json, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I have the following json response which i want to extract.I never used json concept before.Just want to know how can i extract the below json response using DataContractJsonSerializer so that i can extract longname,shortname or any other level attribute.

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&sensor=true

The code i have written doesnt return the element values:

```
       var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(e.Result));
        DataContractJsonSerializer stdserialize = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Address));
        Address stuser = (Address)stdserialize.ReadObject(ms);


   //############################################################################################################################
    [DataContract]
    public class Address
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "long_name")]
        public string address1;
        [DataMember(Name = "short_name")]
        public string shortaddress;
        [DataMember(Name = "formatted_address")]
        public string formattedtaddress;
        [DataMember(Name = "lat")]
        public string latitude;
        [DataMember(Name = "long")]
        public string latitude;
    }
    //##############################################################################################################################
    [DataContract]
    public class result
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "results")]
        public string totalResult { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "address_components")]
        public Dictionary<string, Address> merchants { get; set; }
    }
//###################################################################################################################
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I'd recommend using Json.net for your deserialization, its easy to use, has a WP version and is many times quicker than DataContractJsonSerializer - see http://json.codeplex.com/.

Also, try a browser plugin like Pretty Json for Chrome (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pretty-json/ddngkjbldiejbheifcmnfmmfiniimbbg) which makes it a lot easier to read the json structure when you visit a json url in your browser.

If you do stick with DataContractJsonSerializer though, you're on the right track. You just need to match up your classes to the structure of the Json (that plugin will help you). The outer most object contains a list of address and a text status:

```
[DataContract]
public class Result
{
    [DataMember(Name = "status")]
    public string Status { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "results")]
    public Address[] Results { get; set; }
}
```

Then each of the address objects is like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class Address
{
    [DataMember(Name = "formatted_address")]
    public string FormattedAddress;

    [DataMember(Name = "address_components")]
    public AddressComponent[] AddressComponents;
}
```

They have a list of address components that look like:

```
[DataContract]
public class AddressComponent
{
    [DataMember(Name = "long_name")]
    public string LongName;

    [DataMember(Name = "short_name")]
    public string ShortName;

    [DataMember(Name = "types")]
    public string Types;
}
```

To include long/lat you'd have to have another class as its another level down, e.g. geometry -> location.

You then can deserialize to the outer most object, like this:

```
    var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(e.Result));
    DataContractJsonSerializer stdserialize = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Result));
    Result res = (Result)stdserialize.ReadObject(ms);
```

Then you can look at `res.Results` to go through each address

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I am able to extract the results now.I have also got the json.nets file to my local machine from codeplex.How can i use it my code now ? Do i need to refer any dll from the json.net code files ?

Comment: Yes you will do. The easiest way to do this though would be to install NuGet (http://nuget.org/) as an extension in Visual Studio, then add the reference to Json.net from that